# How can this Prolog predicate become faster than exponential?

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that will check if a room is available within a given schedule(consisting of events).

Checking if the room is available and not taken by another event is currently working in an exponential way. I'd like to optimise this.

What I'm currently doing is:

I take the first event, verify it doesn't overlap with any of the other events. Then I take the second event, I verify it doesn't overlap with any of the other remaining events. And so on until the list is empty.

I've been thinking about it, but the only way I see in order to make this more performant is by using asserts.

I'm wondering if there is any other way than using asserts in order to improve the efficiency?

Comment: How would using asserts make this perform better? When a number of facts are asserted, Prolog still has to search them if you're looking to see if a new query matches. So it doesn't really get rid of the fundamental, exponential issue. How is "overlap" determined? Is there any property of "overlap" that would allow you to skip some overlap checks knowing the results of other overlap checks?

Comment: Prolog programs tend to follow a generate-test cycle. If you benchmark your program, you usually find inefficiency in one or the other: either you generate too many possibilities to check, or your checking is too expensive. It sounds like you have the latter here, and you may be able to improve the situation with a richer data structure--perhaps [an interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)?

Comment: It may be helpful to know how long things are taking, and how many rooms and events you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimal scheduling is definitely an exponential problem. It's akin to optimal bin packing. This is an entire research area.

It sounds to me like what you're doing is O(n<sup>2</sup>): you're comparing every element in the list to every other element in the list. But you're only doing it once, because you're comparing to every element *after* that element in the list. So element 1 gets compared to N-1 other elements, but element N-1 only gets compared to 1 other element. This is not an absurd time complexity for your problem.

An [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) approach is potentially a significant improvement, because you will not actually compare every element to every other element. This lowers your worst-case time complexity to O(N log N) which is considered a pretty big improvement assuming your set of events is large enough that the constant factor cost of using a balanced tree is mitigated.

I suspect this isn't really where your performance problem lies though. You probably don't want the first schedule you can build, you probably want to see what schedule you can make that has the fewest conflicts, which will mean trying different permutations. This is where your algorithm is really running into trouble, and unfortunately it's where my knowledge runs dry; I don't know how one optimizes this process further. But I do know there is a lot written about process theory and scheduling theory that can assist you if you look for it. :)

I don't think your problem comes down to needing to use certain Prolog technologies better, such as the dynamic store. But, you can always profile your code and see where it is spending its time, and maybe there is some low-hanging fruit there that we could solve.

To go much further I think we're going to need to know more about your problem.